# query in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

there are two tables ...know i need

1st condition:
all the records in table

2 nd condition:

In table2 i need only records which have data

...i want one query for the aove two conditions...

Comment: I provided some general ideas but more information will be needed to give a more specific answer.  Table structure, starting data, what is expected as a result would help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.PK = t2.FK
```

This will return all rows in table1 that have at least one corresponding row in table2

But if you want all rows from t1 no matter what then this may be what you want

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.PK = t2.FK
```

Finally, As I dont know the structure in place perhaps table1 and table2 have similar structures.  If this is true perhaps you may want a union of the two

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM Table2 t2
```